# Can $\{n!\log n\}$ converge to $1$?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, limits, factorial, fractional-part

Since $H_n-\log n\to\gamma$ is it correct to deduce that, if $\gamma$ were a rational $a/b $, then $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\{n!H_n-n!\log n\}=\lim_{n\to \infty }\{-n!\log n\}=1-\lim_{n\to \infty }\{n!\log n\}=0$$? If the implication is correct, what is known about $\{n!\log n\}$?

Comment: $n! \log n$ grows so fast that I don't think currently anything can be said about its fractional part... But nice idea! Fourier's proof that $e$ is irrational does something similar, after all.

Comment: Excellent experimentation! Unfotrunately, your implication isn't correct, though mostly for somewhat subtle convergence issues. The fact that $H_n - \log n \to \gamma$ means there is some rate of convergence (which may be quite slow). You are trying to understand something like the fractional part of this error term *after it's multiplied by $n!$*, and $n!$ is gigantic. Thus any approach of this sort should not succeed.

Comment: @ barto, @davidlowryduda Thank you both!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There appear to be two serious errors of thought here.

The first is that $\{ \cdot \} $ is not a continuous function. So, the fact that $a_n \to L$ does not mean you can clude $\{ a_n \} \to \{ L \}$. This would be true if $L$ wasn't an integer, but you are *specifically* interested about the case where it is.

The second problem is that you make absolutely no attempt to control the error of the approximation. In asymptotic notation, that $H_n - \log n \to \gamma$ means

$$ H_n - \log n  = \gamma + o(1) $$

multiplying by $n$ gives

$$ n! H_n - n! \log n = \gamma n! + o(n!) $$

The problem is the error term $o(n!)$ is much too large for you to say *anything* about the fractional part of the right hand side.

Comment: You are totally right, thank you